# On a WPF browser app I want to embedd an image of a live website for displaying SQL reports

Tags: wpf, image

I am hosting SQL reports on a SQL reporting server. Currently I have my page set up to scroll through different reports using the webbrowser tool. Problem is the reports don't scale at all so the reports either have extra white around them or scroll bars. I was thinking that it would be much easier to work with these reports if I could somehow go to there webpage and simply grab a snapshot of the page. Images scale wonderfully in WPF.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've tried playing with the report URL for the last hour or so and managed to get this:

Source="http://utc-rpt-ws/ReportingServer?/SFD/Reports/HourlyPPM&amp;rs:Command=Render&amp;rs:Format=IMAGE&amp;rs:OutputFormat=PNG&amp;rc:Toolbar=False"

The Format=IMAGE&amp;rs:OutputFormat=PNG is suppose to make it an image and format it as a PNG but it is coming back as a TIFF only with an annoying white background and part of the report cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out
I used URL access parameters to have the report server and browser render it as a PNG, then I just used an image and that link in my WPF

```
this.ImageSource = new Uri("http://rpt01-wq02/RptServer?/SFD/Reports/HourlyPPM&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=IMAGE&rc:OutputFormat=PNG&rc:Toolbar=False", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```